# From what anime are these pictures?

Tags: attack-on-titan

From this picture I was unable to identify from doing a Google image search, was this picture from an anime? I am wondering where this is from since I was watching a video clip and it didn't have the names of the animes that were compiled together. This one looks interesting though.

[image]

The only details I have is that she was looking at a guy waving his hair close by to a waterfall and that she hugged this guy in this photo here.

[image]

Comment: Could you split the 3rd image into a separate question. It doesn't appear to be from the same show as the first two.

Comment: Why do I need to create another question. To me it just makes me look like a spam user creating lots of questions.

Comment: It's not spam if they're legit questions. Unlike [so], we *want* more questions. And it's easier to answer if you split them. Since someone might know one, but not the other while someone else does.

Comment: @MiharuDante people in SE sites mostly won't really see that all the questions are from the same person. Bad questions are treated with  downvotes individually, If you want (most important have) 10 relevant unique questions, fire them away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first 2 images appear to be the main characters:

- [Mikasa Ackerman](http://myanimelist.net/character/40881/Mikasa_Ackerman)
- [Eren Yeager](http://myanimelist.net/character/40882/Eren_Yeager)

from [Shingeki no Kyojin (Attack on Titan)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/16498/Shingeki_no_Kyojin).